# Discord.py bot wont print a SIMPLE variable in the chat

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

What I want is for the bot to say `Snacktoshis: 5`, but it won't print the variable in the chat.

Here is my code:

```
from discord import *
from discord.ext import *
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands import *
import random
import asyncio
from discord import Game
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import aiohttp
import discord
import requests
import time

BOT_PREFIX = ("?", "!")
client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

TOKEN ="3812236138921603126360103210983inserttoken21831382ufsfuadha"



@client.command()
async def bal():
    snack = 0
    await client.say("Snacktoshis:",snack)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

My error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send_message() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I know I have alot of unused modules.

Comment: It's probably related to the use of `@client.command()`. Go through their docs again. It probably requires you to provide a function which isn't there, yet. BTW, this assumption is a clear violation of Murphy's law, the holy grail of programming.

Comment: no @KarlRichter

Comment: I don't know what "no" and your "stop" edit means.

Comment: no @KarlRichter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume what you mean is something like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def bal():
  snack = 0
  await bot.say("Snacktoshis: %d" %snack)
```

Where the variable should be part of the message, and not a separate argument to the method call.

Answer (score 2):

From `help('discord.ext.commands.Bot.say')`:

> ```
> discord.ext.commands.Bot.say = say(self, *args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> A helper function that is equivalent to doing
>
> ```
>     self.send_message(message.channel, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

So the four arguments that are being sent into `send_message` from your `client.say` call are `client`, `message.channel`, `"Snacktoshis:"`, and `snack`.  You want the message you're sending to be a single string, instead of two separate arguments.

```
await client.say("Snacktoshis: " + snack)
```

or

```
await client.say("Snacktoshis: {}".format(snack))
```